# How to get attributes from block.js into php

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I want to create a block to display the latest post.
The post are loading as it should but i want to use "props.attributes.selectAllignment" and pass that as a class inside the php function. This props.attributes.selectAllignmentwill output "left right or center" as a class.
I can directly put the class in the html in php but I want to give the user the ability to select the class from InspectorControls

Block.js code as below

```
registerBlockType("buik/block-lead", {

title: __("Lead Block"), 
icon: "minus",
category: "layout",
keywords: [__("lead "), __("lead bootstrap"), __("buik")],
attributes: {
    heading: {
        type: "string",
        default:
            "Lead paragraph. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.",
    },
    customClass: {
        type: "string",
    },
    selectAllignment: {
        type: "string",
        default: "",
    },
    cover: {
        type: "string",
        default: "", // keep it empty so it doesn't get saved in the post content
    },
},

edit: (props) => {
    const focus = props.focus;

    const onChangeheading = (value) => {
        props.setAttributes({ heading: value });
    };

    const { selectAllignment } = props.attributes;

    function onChangeselectAllignment(newValue) {
        props.setAttributes({ selectAllignment: newValue });
    }

    const blockProps = useBlockProps();
    const posts = useSelect((select) => {
        return select("core").getEntityRecords("postType", "post", {
            per_page: 3,
        });
    }, []);

    return [
        <div className={props.className}>
            {!posts && "Loading"}
            {posts && posts.length === 0 && "No Posts"}
            {posts && posts.length > 0 && (
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        {posts.map((post) => {
                            return (
                                <li
                                    style={{
                                        textAlign: `${props.attributes.selectAllignment}`,
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <img src={post.fimg_url} />
                                    <a href={post.link}>{post.title.rendered}</a>
                                </li>
                            );
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )}

            <RichText
                tagName="p"
                placeholder="Edit paragraph "
                className={selectField}
                focus={focus}
                value={props.attributes.heading}
                onChange={onChangeheading}
                keepPlaceholderOnFocus={true}
            />
        </div>,
        <InspectorControls>
            <SelectControl
                label="Text alignment"
                value={selectAllignment}
                options={[
                    { value: "left", label: "default" },
                    { value: "center", label: "Center" },
                    { value: "left", label: "Left" },
                    { value: "right", label: "Right" },
                ]}
                onChange={onChangeselectAllignment}
            />
        </InspectorControls>,
    ];
},


save: (props) => {
    return null;
},
```

});

php code that renders the output in frontend

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'register_latest_post');
function register_latest_post() {
    register_block_type('buik/block-lead', [ 'render_callback' => 'render_latest_post'
    ]);
}
function render_latest_post() {
$latest_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( [

    'numberposts' => 3,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    ] );
if(empty($latest_posts)){
    return '<p>No posts</p>';
}
$posts_output = '<div class="latest-postss">'; 
foreach($latest_posts as $post ) {

$post_id = $post['ID'];

$post_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, 'full' );
$posts_output .= '<div class="post-title ">
                        <img src="'. $post_thumbnail .'" class="img-fluid" loading="lazy" />
                        <h2>
                            <a href="'.get_permalink($post_id). '">
                                '.get_the_title( $post_id ).'
                            </a>
                        </h2>
                        
                  </div>';
}
$posts_output .= '</div>';

return $posts_output;

}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_rest_images' );
function register_rest_images(){
    register_rest_field( array('post'),
        'fimg_url',
        array(
        'get_callback' => 'get_rest_featured_image',
        'update_callback' => null,
        'schema' => null,
        )
    );
}
function get_rest_featured_image( $object, $field_name, $request) { if( $object['featured_media'] ) {
    $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $object['featured_media'], 'app-thumb' ); return $img[0];
}
return false;
}
```

function parse_blocks1( $content ) {

```
$parser_class = apply_filters( 'block_parser_class', 'WP_Block_Parser' );

$parser = new $parser_class();
return $parser->parse( $content );
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `render_callback` function receives the block attributes as the first argument:

```
function render_latest_post( $attributes ) {
    $column_size = $attributes['columnSize'];
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: i get this error: Undefined variable $attributes i am sorry I dont know much php.

Comment: Updated the question and the code.

Comment: Your updated code isn’t using my suggestion?

Comment: I tried. It gives an error Undefined variable $column_size 

    function render_latest_post1( $attributes ) {
        $column_size = $attributes['selectAllignment'];
    }
Since the function render_latest_post()  already exist I added  function render_latest_post1()

Comment: Are you also using the render function somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. Same php 

function render_latest_post() {
    $latest_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( [
    
        'numberposts' => 3,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
        ] );

Comment: The code you've added doesn't make sense. You've added an extra function `render_latest_post1` that isn't use anywhere. You need to add the attributes parameter and variable to the function you're using as the `render_callback`.